# Change header background on scroll

Tags: javascript, header, scroll

I'm trying to change the header background of a page on scroll.

I'm using the code below. The JS is working, when scrolling greater than 100px I can see the class .not-transparent being added to the  element in HMTL. The problem is, that class isn't being subsequently being called in the CSS.

Here's the HTML:

```
<header>
    <div id="logo">logo</div>
    <div id="nav-wrapper">
        <nav>
            nav
        </nav>
    </div>
    <div class="clear"></div>
</header>
<script>
$(window).on("scroll", function () {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
        $("header").addClass("not-transparent");
    }
    else {
        $("header").removeClass("not-transparent");
    }
});
</script>
```

Here's the CSS

```
header {
    width:100%;
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    z-index:3;
}
header.not-transparent {
    background: #252525;    
}
```

Comment: you can use background color in its header class rather then done below.

Comment: As scroll is constantly fired when scrolling your script continues to add the class ("not-transparent"). jQuery is smart enough to allow this to happen only once. Other code may require some more logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use css property for it as.

```
 <script>
 $(window).on("scroll", function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > 100) {
       $("header").css("background","#252525");
    }
    else {
       $("header").css("background","#fff");
    }
 });
 </script>
```

Make sure that your child div background is set to transparent so that you can see parent div background.

Comment: I like this approach. Is there a way to make it fade in gracefully?

Comment: you can use css transistion effect. Look at it.

Comment: for some reason this answer doesent change the background of mine navbar (im using a fixed-top navbar) form bootstrap... any idea why?